# Fields to be filled by the buyer in magento product page

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I was looking for but couldn't find something like this.
I need to create a product page, where the buyer will fill in some text fields before adding the product to the cart.

Something mostly like this page do: http://bitly.com/Sw4jzR

When added to the cart, it need to save the fields too.

Anyone have seen something like this done in magento yet? Have any idea of how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use *Custom Options*. Here's a link to the [tutorial](http://www.magentoadvisor.com/magento-backup/complex-magento-products-part-2-simple-products-with-custom-options/).

Comment: Use a text box custom option. The user fills it in and it gets sent along with the order. We use this for vinyl lettering we sell.

Comment: Thanks Josh Davenport, Fiasco Labs and Slayer Birden, this is exactly what i need... Will be almost the same as you do it today for the Vinyl Lettering.