# Magento drop down to be selected by buyer

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. The website I am working on sells contact lenses and some custom attributes need to be added on the product page. Now requirement states that user has to select some prescription values from drop-down fields before adding the product to cart. I am totally lost on how to do it. This question asks the same thing:

[Fields to be filled by the buyer in magento product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690228/fields-to-be-filled-by-the-buyer-in-magento-product-page)

But the answer points to dead link. How to retrieve some custom information from user on product page and store it along with order?

Comment: do you want to achieve this using custom option ? Or the options are same for or products so you want custom code ?

Comment: @PankajPareek the custom attribute will be applied to whole category. So ideally a solution where admin doesn't have to define custom attributes for each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with custom option. Magento provide custom option facility. when you create custom option then it displayed on product page and you will get information from customer and that information stored in order automatically.

reference link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfZCXjWqrSM

Comment: SimBeez is it possible to do this for whole category instead of individual products?

Comment: Yes but for that you have to buy one extension.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html

Comment: Using this extension you can not assign custom option category wise but you can assign custom option multiple products.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Dynamic custom option. I have answered thw whole process here:
[dynamically add product custom options magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123916/dynamically-add-product-custom-options-magento/27124771#27124771)

As the Custom option applicaple to particular category. so you need to add required conditionon on precription form on product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this using custom option and there is a great module available in magento connect to achieve your goal.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manger.html